# PHAssetChangeRequest always returns nil when creating video assets

Tags: ios, ios8, photosframework, phasset

I am saving a newly-created video file in the local Documents. I would then like to copy it into the Photo Library using the Photos framework.

Problem is, even though the video is being written out (and I can confirm it's there and viewable), the following creation request always return nil:

```
[[PHPhotoLibrary sharedPhotoLibrary] performChanges:^{

    // NSString filePath points to the newly-created file in Documents directory
    NSParameterAssert([[NSFileManager defaultManager] isReadableFileAtPath:filePath]);
    // path looks fine

    NSURL* url = [NSURL URLWithString:filePath];
    PHAssetChangeRequest* createAssetRequest = [PHAssetChangeRequest creationRequestForAssetFromVideoAtFileURL:url];

    // got back nil from creationRequestForAssetFromVideoAtFileURL, so we will assert out here
    NSParameterAssert(createAssetRequest);
}
completionHandler:^(BOOL success, NSError *error) {}];
```

Answer (score 0):

Not surprisingly, the URL was the problem. `url = [NSURL URLWithString:filePath]` does not point to the movie file.  It's fine if I get `url` in (for example) the following way:

```
NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
NSURL *documentsURL = [[fileManager URLsForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory inDomains:NSUserDomainMask] lastObject];
NSArray *contents = [fileManager contentsOfDirectoryAtURL:documentsURL
                                       includingPropertiesForKeys:@[]
                                                          options:NSDirectoryEnumerationSkipsHiddenFiles
                                                            error:nil];
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"lastPathComponent == 'movie.mov'"];
NSURL* url = nil;
for (NSURL *fileURL in [contents filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate]) {
    url = fileURL;
}
```

Comment: let temporaryVideoURL = NSURL.fileURLWithPath(outputPath)! works as an input to a change request as well

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `NSURL* url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:filePath];`. This is my demo code, work well for me:

```
[[PHPhotoLibrary sharedPhotoLibrary] performChanges:^{
    NSURL *localFileUrl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:localSavedPath];
    PHAssetChangeRequest *assetChangeRequest = [PHAssetChangeRequest creationRequestForAssetFromVideoAtFileURL:localFileUrl];
    if (localAssetCollection != nil) {
        PHAssetCollectionChangeRequest *assetCollectionChangeRequest = [PHAssetCollectionChangeRequest changeRequestForAssetCollection:localAssetCollection];
        [assetCollectionChangeRequest addAssets:@[[assetChangeRequest placeholderForCreatedAsset]]];
    }
} completionHandler:^(BOOL success, NSError *error) {
}];
```

My demo also support change the assets collection.